# Leaflet popup tip not aligned properly

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet, popup, mapping

Popups I have on this leaflet map have a mis aligned tip
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

This the code I have for the markers themselves and the associated popup

```
var redIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
    shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1,-34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
    });

var map_data = {!! json_encode($map_data) !!};

map_data.forEach(element => {

    console.log('program=' + element.program + ', lat=' + element.gps_lat + ', long=' + element.gps_lon);

    data[i] = L.marker([element.gps_lon, element.gps_lat], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(map);
    
    data[i].bindPopup(
        // + ' <form action="{{ route("opentraining") }}" method="POST" class="formEditTraining">@csrf<input type="hidden" name="training_id" value='+ element.id  + '>'+ element.project +'</form>'
        '<strong>' + element.program + '</strong>'
        + '<br />'
        + '<b>Location:</b> ' + element.location + ', ' + element.district + ', ' + element.province
        + '<br />'
        + '<b>Description:</b> ' + element.description
        + '<br /><br />'
        + '<a href="" target="_blank" onClick="openRecord(' + element.id + ')">View Record</a> '
        ).openPopup();
    i++;
});
```

[image]

Comment: Inspect which CSS rules are currently applying to the popup's elements. Look for the ones overriding Leaflet's CSS rules.

Comment: Sorry for late one.. I found the css related to the popup tip and tried overriding it in a custom_styles.css file. Upon refresh the result is still the same... is that not the place to override all styling issues in a laravel project?

Comment: Update: Just tried styling it right on the page itself and that worked so will go with that thanks